How is this function piece-wise linear?
I encountered this lemma in a research paper related to End-to-End inventory management model.
Please note that $d_{[t_1,t_2]} = \sum_{t=t_1}^{t_2} d_t$, where $d_t$ denotes demand at time instance t. $I_{t_1}$ denotes the inventory level at time $t_1$.
I could understand why $f(a)$ is a convex function. But I didn't understand why is it a piece-wise function. Subsequenly, I am not able to visualize how the function has extreme points at $d_{[t_1,s]}-I_{t_1}$?
Can you please help me understand how $f(a)$ is a piece-wise function and how it has extreme points at $d_{[t_1,s]}-I_{t_1}$?
Thanks in advance!


it is sum of piecewise linear functions

Thanks for the comment @Exodd. Is there any way I can visualize this function. Sorry if the question seems naive, but I am new to this field.
Also, how are the extreme points of the function  $d[t_{1},s]−I_{t_1}$?

Visualize $h[I_{t_1}+a-d_{[t_1,s]}]^+$. It has only one vertex exactly at $-I_{t_1}+d_{[t_1,s]}$. The sum of these functions will have the union of the vertices

But why cant it have a vertex at $ −I_{t_1}+d_{[t_1,s]} + 1$? After all, $[.]^{+}$ denotes $max( . , 0)$? Also, can you please cite some sources from where I can read more about such functions?

Cross-posted: https://or.stackexchange.com/questions/12137/how-is-this-function-piece-wise-linear
